# How to run my programm to process email attachment of specified type on iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, file-type, email

I need to run my iPhone application when user gets email with attachment of specified type and process it. For example "some.jpg". How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to take over a basic file type like this on the iPhone.  The closest you can come is to implement your own custom URL scheme, which would let you have your application be launched in the same sorts of circumstances if you're the one sending the email...

What this means is that you could make it so an email link like

```
myspecialimage://mycoolserver.com/some.jpg
```

launches your special application when a user clicks in.

See [this link](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html) or the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html) for guidance.